# Flutter Web: How to fix SelectableText alignment?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I have a [SelectableText](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SelectableText-class.html) and `Icon` inside a `Row`, but `SelectableText` does not seem to be properly aligned.

**Right now it looks like this,**

[image]

**Expected Result:**

[image]

This is code I am using,

```
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.whatsapp),
            const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8)),
            SelectableText(
              '+91-8**2**8**5',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
            )
          ],
        ),
```

PS: It works well with `Text` but I want `SelectableText` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue **Selectabletext widget on web is cutted on half** 
 https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40663 has been solved. 
please upgrade to latest version 
attached my full test code and result

[image]

full test code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(        
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {      
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {   
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(        
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(        
        child: Column(          
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                const Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.whatsapp),
                const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8)),
                SelectableText(
                  '+91-8**2**8**5',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
                )
              ],
            ),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), 
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How on earth I could not figure this out! Actually I switched to master channel it downloaded some stuff and I thought I am running the latest version. thank you very much.